# What to replace potassium orotate with?

Tags: supplements

First of all, I'm **not** endorsing this supplement here. Scientific literature generally describes it as inefficient, but in my particular case it seems to be working, is all. There's zero guarantee that it would work the same way for anyone else.

The problem is that I'm moving to a country where potassium orotate just doesn't appear in either drug or sport nutrition stores. Hauling a several months worth amount of anything remotely drug-related over the border is bound to arise questions. I'd like to find a replacement.

Please note that

1. The key here is not potassium but the orotic acid.
2. Being middle-aged and physically active, I've experimented with many legally available substances considered 'energy supplements' for what it's worth. Creatine, carnitine, etc. don't do anything for me. No idea why. I need something chemically close to orotic acid.

P.S. No worries; [posted it on the health site](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/14212/what-to-replace-potassium-orotate-with).